# Binding to multiple controls and setting with the CLR

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a Page that has Multiple tabitems that I have setup as usercontrols

**EventPage:**

```
<Page x:Class="Outreach_Alpha2.Pages._2_Outreach._2_1_3_OutreachEventPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:eventTabs="clr-namespace:Outreach_Alpha2.Pages._2_Outreach._2_1_EventTabs"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="1200"
      Loaded="OutreachEventPage_Loaded"
      Title="Outreach Events">
    <TabControl Style="{StaticResource TabControlStyle}">
        <TabItem Header="Event Details" x:Name="EventDetailsTab">
            <eventTabs:_1_EventDetailsTab/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Organization" x:Name="OrganizationTab">
            <eventTabs:_2_OrganizationTab/>
        </TabItem>
</Page>
```

**EventPage (Backend):**

```
public partial class _2_1_3_OutreachEventPage : Page
{
    public _2_1_3_OutreachEventPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new OutreachEventViewModel();
    }
}
```

**Event Details Tab (UserControl):**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Outreach_Alpha2.Pages._2_Outreach._2_1_EventTabs._1_EventDetailsTab"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
             xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             x:Name="EventDetailsControl">
    <!-- Organization -->
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Organizations}" SelectedValue="{Binding OrganizationName}" />
</UserControl
```

**Organization Info Tab (UserControl):**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Outreach_Alpha2.Pages._2_Outreach._2_1_EventTabs._2_OrganizationTab"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Name="OrganizationTab">
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Organizations}" SelectedValue="{Binding OrganizationName}" />
</UserControl>
```

**OutreachEventViewModel:**

```
namespace Outreach_Alpha2.MVVM.OutreachEvents
{
    class OutreachEventViewModel
    {
        //SQL TableAdapters & DataTables
        internal readonly TitleListTableAdapter TitleListTableAdapter = new TitleListTableAdapter();
        internal readonly OrganizationListTableAdapter OrganizationListTableAdapter = new OrganizationListTableAdapter();

        //ViewModel that populates the contact listbox
        public OutreachEventViewModel()
        {
            //Perform SQL querys
            var organizations = OrganizationListTableAdapter.GetOrganizationList();

            //Declare needed variables
            var organizationList = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            //Store SQL results into lists
            organizationList.AddRange((IEnumerable)(from DataRow row in organizations.Rows select row.ItemArray[0].ToString()));
            Organizations = organizationList;

        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> Organizations { get; set; }


    }
    public class OrganizationData : ViewModelBase
    {
        private string _organizationName;
        private string _street1;
        private string _street2;
        private string _city;
        private string _state;
        private string _zip;
        private string _county;
        private string _serviceArea;

        internal readonly OrgByNameTableAdapter OrgByNameTableAdapter = new OrgByNameTableAdapter();

        public string OrganizationName
        {
            get { return _organizationName; }
            set
            {
                _organizationName = value;
                UpdateOrganizationData(value);
                OnPropertyChanged("OrganizationName");

            }
        }

        public string OrgStreet1
        {
            get { return _street1; }
            set
            {
                if (_street1 != value)
                {
                    Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "OrgStreet1" });
                    _street1 = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("OrgStreet1");
                }
            }
        }

        public string OrgStreet2
        {
            get { return _street2; }
            set
            {
                if (_street2 != value)
                {
                    Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "OrgStreet2" });
                    _street2 = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("OrgStreet2");
                }
            }
        }

        public string OrgCity
        {
            get { return _city; }
            set
            {
                if (_street1 != value)
                {
                    Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "OrgCity" });
                    _city = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("OrgCity");
                }
            }
        }

        public string OrgState
        {
            get { return _state; }
            set
            {
                if (_state != value)
                {
                    Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "OrgState" });
                    _state = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("OrgState");
                }
            }
        }

        public string OrgZip
        {
            get { return _zip; }
            set
            {
                if (_zip != value)
                {
                    Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "OrgZip" });
                    _zip = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("OrgZip");
                }
            }
        }

        public string OrgCounty
        {
            get { return _county; }
            set
            {
                if (_county != value)
                {
                    Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "OrgCounty" });
                    _county = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("OrgCounty");
                }
            }
        }

        public string OrgServiceArea
        {
            get { return _serviceArea; }
            set
            {
                if (_serviceArea != value)
                {
                    Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "OrgServiceArea" });
                    _serviceArea = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("OrgServiceArea");
                }
            }
        }

        private void UpdateOrganizationData(string orgName)
        {
            var organizationData = OrgByNameTableAdapter.GetOrganizationByName(orgName);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(orgName))
            {
                OrgStreet1 = organizationData.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
                OrgStreet2 = organizationData.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
                OrgCity = organizationData.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
                OrgState = organizationData.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
                OrgZip = organizationData.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
                OrgCounty = organizationData.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
                OrgServiceArea = organizationData.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On both the ***Event Details Tab*** and the ***Organization Info Tab*** the ***OrganizationName*** is bound the same way. However when I update one the other does not change accordingly. The ultimate objective is for them to change in sync and then when it changes the organization information would update with the address information on the ***Organization Info Tab***. It is not working as planned though. Any insight would be appreciated.

I'm thinking I have to somehow initialize an ***OrganizationData*** type and bind it to the dockpanel somehow, but I do not know how to do that.